# html5 audio and WebAudio are BFFs - are they?

Tags: html, audio, web-audio-api

i am coding on a custom player for quite a while now.
My plan was to use soundcloud as my backend. And the HTML5 audio Tag as my streaming object.
I also want to include a Canvas for a bit of visualisation. And thats were the problem starts.

For the Visuals to work on both Browsers, I need to load the audio into an arraybuffer via xhr request. But then I can't use the audio Tag anymore. Which is sad, because by now I know how to code all the functionality i need based on it.

I found the article on html5rocks about html5 audio and WebAudio being best friends.
There is also an example on how to use the tag with an frequency bar visualizer. BUT
this only works on Chrome, because Firefox - maybe some of you have noticed - will play .mp3 files but inside a video object. For the visuals to work I would need .ogg files for Firefox. But then i can't use soundcloud as my backend anymore.

So do i have to rethink the whole player - or is there a way to decode the audio on both browsers while using html 5 audio?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

That's an issue with FF  (no MP3 support in <audio>).  But can't you get a media stream from the  element also?  It shouldn't matter that it's a  not an  - audioContext.createMediaElementSource should work on that, too.